# Run application with Quartz scheduler in different time zones

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I have two virtual machines with my application instance on the board. The application uses quartz scheduler configured to work in cluster mode. Both virtual machines are in UTС timezone.

I want to start my own(local) applications instance. But my machine(Europe/Moscow) has different time zone with vm.

Question is: is it safe to run my application instance? If not, what should I do?

Comment: Not too clear on your question.  You run your app instance locally.  Is it related with the apps running in the vm?

Comment: Yes, my local instance (local env) related to app running on vm(dev env) they are simply share one database. In advance, the answer: yes, it's safe to run application.

Answer (score 0):

Even you are using quartz-scheduler,  you can also specify the timezone to get a consistent behavior.
If you want the job running at different timeZone, you can create your own Bean of timeZone.
e.g.

```
<bean id="timeZone" class="java.util.TimeZone" factory-method="getTimeZone">
　　<constructor-arg>
　　　　<value>GMT+4:00</value>  // Europe/Moscow 
　　</constructor-arg>
</bean>
```